# Create a method that returns a set of records FROM different table that can be used as a view

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

```
create function fruit(proses varchar)
returns table("FRUIT" varchar, "ID" integer, "FRUITCOLOR" varchar, "PRICE" varchar, "PAY" varchar, "CHANGE" varchar) as
--fruit,id,fruitcolor is from table1, but price, pay, change is from table2 
$$
begin
  if proses = 'view1' then
    return query
    select fruit, id from table1;
  elseif proses = 'view2' then
    return query
    select fruit, id, fruitcolor, price, pay, change from table, table2;
  end if;
  return;
end;
$$ 
language plpgsql;
```

this time, I don't know how to get that from different table,
honestly, I've tried someway, but this is what happen:

> Number of returned columns (3) does not match expected column count (6).

and this:

> ERROR: column reference «fruit» ambiguous (has two meanings),

Comment: Please remember to always provide your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### PL/pgSQL Function fixed

The **number of column and their data type** must match the defined row type in `RETURNS TABLE` (column names are irrelevant *as long as they are unambiguous*):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fruit(proses text)
  RETURNS TABLE("FRUIT" varchar, "ID" integer, "FRUITCOLOR" varchar, "PRICE" varchar
              , "PAY" varchar, "CHANGE" varchar) AS
$func$
BEGIN 
   IF proses = 'view1' then
      RETURN query
      SELECT fruit, id, NULL::varchar, NULL::varchar, NULL::varchar, NULL::varchar
      FROM   table1;

   ELSIF proses = 'view2' THEN
      RETURN query
      SELECT fruit, id, fruitcolor, price, pay, change FROM table2;
      --                                   NOT: from table, table2;
   END IF;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

About typing constants:

- [I have a delete-insert CTE that fails in a strange manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211294/i-have-a-delete-insert-cte-that-fails-in-a-strange-manner/31211776#31211776)

About naming conflicts in functions:

- [Postgres Function NULL value for row that references NEW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166902/postgres-function-null-value-for-row-that-references-new/12172475#12172475)
- [Naming conflict between function parameter and result of JOIN with USING clause](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/105902/3684)

#### Simpler with plain SQL:

As long as your code is as simple as displayed, you can radically simplify:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fruit(proses text)
  RETURNS TABLE("FRUIT" varchar, "ID" integer, "FRUITCOLOR" varchar, "PRICE" varchar
              , "PAY" varchar, "CHANGE" varchar) AS
$func$
SELECT fruit, id, fruitcolor, price, pay, change FROM table2;
WHERE proses = 'view1'

UNION ALL
SELECT fruit, id, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM table1
WHERE proses = 'view2'
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

Only ***one***  (or no) `SELECT` will touch the table. For the other(s), the `WHERE` condition is always false (or null), so no rows are returned from those.

Note how I don't have to add type casts to the added NULL values this time. That's because a `UNION` query derives column names and types from the first `SELECT`. The rest is coerced to the same row type - or an error occurs if that's not possible.

This is not going to be faster, just simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Your both selects should return the same type of columns. In your case "varchar, integer, varchar, varchar, varchar, varchar". Therefore you can add null values in the first query instead of the missing columns. Also you need to specify the table name of each variable in selects when writing functions as in

```
SELECT table1.fruit, table1.id, NULL::varchar, NULL::varchar, NULL::varchar, NULL::varchar FROM table1
```

Comment: True, but you need type cast, too.